Is the (set of non-unit integer affine transformations) the (free vector space over the unit affine transformations) of the 2-adic numbers?
I'm trying to apply this excerpt from Wikipedia to an affine space of my own making:

Unlike for vectors in a vector space, in an affine space there is no distinguished point that serves as an origin. There is no predefined concept of adding or multiplying points together, or multiplying a point by a scalar number. However, for any affine space, an associated vector space can be constructed from the differences between start and end points, which are called free vectors, displacement vectors, translation vectors or simply translations.[1] Likewise, it makes sense to add a displacement vector to a point of an affine space, resulting in a new point translated from the starting point by that vector. While points cannot be arbitrarily added together, it is meaningful to take affine combinations of points: weighted sums with numerical coefficients summing to 1, resulting in another point. These coefficients define a barycentric coordinate system for the flat through the points.

Let $f_{a,b}(x):\Bbb Z_2^\times\to\Bbb Z_2:a,b\in\Bbb Z_2^\times$ be an affine transformation from the 2-adic units to the 2-adic non-integers, parametrized by a pair of 2-adic units a,b and given by:
$f_{a,b}(x)=ax+b$.
Let's call these the unit-affine transformations.
Let $A^\times$ be the space over all $:a,b\in\Bbb Z_2^\times$ of all such affine transformations on $x$.  It's unconventional I believe to make this restriction to $:a,b\in\Bbb Z_2^\times$ but is it in any sense wrong?
Then by the above paragraph, there exists a vector space of the free vectors of this affine space which is given by the set of all differences between two such affine transformations.  Let's call this the non-unit transformations and denote it $A$:
$A=\{f_{a,b}(x)=x\mapsto ax+b:a,b\in\Bbb Z_2\setminus\Bbb Z_2^\times\}$
This time, $a,b$ range over the non-unit integers, correct?  Because the sum or difference of two units will always be a non-unit integer.
Is it correct that $A$, the set of non-unit integer affine transformations, is the free vector space over the unit-affine transformations $A^\times$, of the 2-adic numbers?

What do you mean by "parametrized by a pair of 2-adic units $a,b$". Parametrized in what way? Different parametrizations would lead to different $A^\times$. How do you know that the result would be an affine space? "2-adic" makes no difference here. It is the definition of "affine space" over a field that allows you to show that the offsets between pairs of points in the affine space form a vector space over the same field, regardless of the field, and exactly how the affine space is constructed.

@PaulSinclair Thank-you very much for asking.  Your question highlighted an omission which I have now fixed.  By "parametrized" I mean that the functions $f$ are parametrized by the pair $a,b$ and that $a,b$ are not operands of the functions whereas $x$ is the operand.  The 2-adics are relevant here, insofar as the functions which constitute the points in my space are restricted to acting from the 2-adic units onto the 2-adic non-unit integers. Since that contradicts what you wrote, maybe that defeats my idea that this is an affine space?
